# Laravel Eloquent - Return Users with specific role (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an application where I want to find all the users (from a specified client) with a certain role (in this case Super Admin)

A client can have many users

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

A user can belong to many roles

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

I want to be able to return all the users from a client with a specific role.

So in the Client Model I want something like:

```
public function superAdmins() {
    return ... // NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `hasMany(User::class)->whereHas('roles', function($query){return $query->where('name', 'super');})`? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @SuperDJ - I'd just managed to achieve something very similar but not quite as good. This works a treat. Add it as an answer and I'll give you the credit

Comment: Alternatively, since you already have `public function users()` on your `Client` model: `return $this->users()->whereHas('roles', function ($query) { ... });` - You can chain relationships instead of redefining `hasMany(User::class)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining relations you can add `where()` statements as well.

This means you can use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```php
public function superAdmins() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class)
              ->whereHas('roles', function($query) {
                  return $query->where('name', 'super');
              });
}
```

Comment: Can I use the same in the user.php